# Armitage Java error, Cannot find Java?

Tags: java, security

Currently I'm taking a security course and we have to use `Metasploit`.

Install went smooth on `osx 10.9` but when I try to use armitage I got this error:

```
/usr/local/bin/armitage: line 1: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Does this mean armitage cannot find Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type `java -version` in console, and if java is not installed, download http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Comment: Java 1.6 is installed.

Comment: does the page with java applet works? e.g. http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre

Comment: Did the trick, seems i was using a unsupported version of the plugin. Thanks man!